# Not able to send info to LCD

Tags: avr, atmel, avrdude, atmelstudio

I studied this code in one of the youtube tutorials, I cannot send info to LCD, the program shows error, the error which I keep getting is

```
Initializing argument 1 of 'void Send_A_String(char*)' [-fpermissive]
initializing argument 3 of 'void Send_An_IntegerToMrLCD(uint8_t, uint8_t, int, char)' [-fpermissive]
invalid conversion from 'char' to 'char*' [-fpermissive]
invalid conversion from 'char*' to 'int' [-fpermissive]
```

Below is the header file for LCD - MrLCD.h

```
#ifndef MrLCD
#define MrLCD

#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MrLCDsCrib PORTB
#define DataDir_MrLCDsCrib DDRB
#define MrLCDsControl PORTD
#define DataDir_MrLCDsControl DDRD
#define LightSwitch 5
#define ReadWrite 7
#define BiPolarMood 2

char firstColumnPositionsForMrLCD[4] = {0, 64, 20, 84};

void Check_IF_MrLCD_isBusy(void);
void Peek_A_Boo(void);
void Send_A_Command(unsigned char command);
void Send_A_Character(unsigned char character);
void Send_A_String(char *StringOfCharacters);
void initializeMrLCD(void);
void GotoMrLCDsLocation(uint8_t x, uint8_t y);
void Send_A_StringToMrLCDWithLocation(uint8_t x, uint8_t y, char *StringOfCharacters);
void Send_An_IntegerToMrLCD(uint8_t x, uint8_t y, int IntegerToDisplay, char NumberOfDigits);


void Check_IF_MrLCD_isBusy()
{
    DataDir_MrLCDsCrib = 0;
    MrLCDsControl |= 1<<ReadWrite;
    MrLCDsControl &= ~1<<BiPolarMood;

    while (MrLCDsCrib >= 0x80)
    {
        Peek_A_Boo();
    }

    DataDir_MrLCDsCrib = 0xFF;
}
void Peek_A_Boo()
{
    MrLCDsControl |= 1<<LightSwitch;
    asm volatile ("nop");
    asm volatile ("nop");
    MrLCDsControl &= ~1<<LightSwitch;
}

void Send_A_Command(unsigned char command)
{
    Check_IF_MrLCD_isBusy();
    MrLCDsCrib = command;
    MrLCDsControl &= ~ ((1<<ReadWrite)|(1<<BiPolarMood));
    Peek_A_Boo();
    MrLCDsCrib = 0;
}

void Send_A_Character(unsigned char character)
{
    Check_IF_MrLCD_isBusy();
    MrLCDsCrib = character;
    MrLCDsControl &= ~ (1<<ReadWrite);
    MrLCDsControl |= 1<<BiPolarMood;
    Peek_A_Boo();
    MrLCDsCrib = 0;
}

void Send_A_String(char *StringOfCharacters)
{
    while(*StringOfCharacters > 0)
    {
        Send_A_Character(*StringOfCharacters++);
    }
}

void initializeMrLCD()
{
    DataDir_MrLCDsControl |= 1<<LightSwitch | 1<<ReadWrite | 1<<BiPolarMood;
    _delay_ms(15);

    Send_A_Command(0x01); //Clear Screen 0x01 = 00000001
    _delay_ms(2);
    Send_A_Command(0x38);
    _delay_us(50);
    Send_A_Command(0b00001110);
    _delay_us(50);
}

void GotoMrLCDsLocation(uint8_t x, uint8_t y)
{
    Send_A_Command(0x80 + firstColumnPositionsForMrLCD[y-1] + (x-1));
}

void Send_A_StringToMrLCDWithLocation(uint8_t x, uint8_t y, char *StringOfCharacters)
{
    GotoMrLCDsLocation(x, y);
    Send_A_String(*StringOfCharacters);
}

void Send_An_IntegerToMrLCD(uint8_t x, uint8_t y, int IntegerToDisplay, char NumberOfDigits)
{
    char StringToDisplay[NumberOfDigits];
    itoa(IntegerToDisplay, StringToDisplay, 10);
    Send_A_StringToMrLCDWithLocation(x, y, StringToDisplay); 
    Send_A_String(" ");
}

#endif
```

And in the simplest of programs in the main file, if I try to call these functions in the header file like Send_A_StringToMrLCDWithLocation or Send_An_IntegerToMrLCD... The program shows error...

Answer (score 0):

You need to move all this code into a C file, i.e. MrLCD.c because that is where the code is instantiated.

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: appologies, I wanted to change it but i don't have enough reputations to comment on the question...

Answer (score 0):

You have not included the .c file where you call these functions, but the error appears to say that you are calling the functions with the wrong type of variables.

You are calling `void Send_A_String(char*)` with a `char` rather than a pointer to a string.

You are calling `void Send_An_IntegerToMrLCD(uint8_t, uint8_t, int, char)` with a char pointer (string) rather than an int in the third parameter.